# 2 domains 1 ftp server that redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ftp

I have 1 ftp server which I used for 1 domain to redirect all subdomains to www.domain.com

I used this code `RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 / http://www.google.com/`

Which worked perfectly for 1 domain. I now bought another domain and would like to make an if statement somehow similar to this in .htaccess

```
if(site == *.domain1.com)
redirect to www.domain1.com

if(site == *.domain2.com)
redirect to www.domain2.com
```

I dont really want to explain why I use an ftp server to redirect my urls as it would take up too much space, but this is my only option so to say.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: uh, ftp has absolutely nothing to do with http... it is not possible for an ftp server to redirect ANYTHING.

Comment: Uhm, I dont know. I just got it for free and thought it was like that, must be a normal webhost then..

Answer (score 2):

I solved it, for those interested.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain1.com/? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain2.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
```